# How to navegate to viewAreas betewen diferent Classes and Experiements?

Tags: anylogic

I´m trying to implement a menu Bar.

The idea is an initial viewArea in Simulation Experiment to setup parameters of the model. Then I would like to be able to navegate to Main or to "UI" Class to show some KPIs, and then go back to a viewArea in Simulation Experiment.

I was able to implement a menubar to viewAreas inside Main only.
How to navegate to viewAreas on Simulation Experiment or other classes ?

Comment: Do you mean navigating to viewAreas inside other agents?

Comment: yes, Yashar. I have viewAreas in Main, SimulationExperiment and other agents. For example: From SimulatonExperiment, I´m trying to call an viewArea inside Main using getEngine().getRoot().viewArea.navegateTo(). but I got an error: "viewArea cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: try this:
((Main)getEngine().getRoot).viewArea.navigateTo()

Comment: Welcome to SOF. Please add details to your question, this depends a lot on the actual setup and where you try this. Here are some more tips to win at StackOverflow for AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Felipe's comment you can use `((Main)getEngine().getRoot()).viewArea.navigateTo();`

But it will only work if the engine has already started running, else Main has not yet been instantiated.